# How to rewrite url in codelgniter

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

Hello First i tell all of you that in codelgniter framework i am new and i have a problem related to my url the url looks like this
http://www.vacationplannersnetwork.com/search/name/france

but i want my URL looks like this 
http://www.vacationplannersnetwork.com/france

I do search engine optimization of this website so i want this type of structure ,so if anyone knows then please help me its highly recommended.thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done over rerouteing.
In your `APPPATH . 'routes.php'` file add this line:

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'search/name/$1';
```

Since you want to have first URI segment matching your results, you would need to add other specific routes before that one. For example:

```
$route['contact-us'] = 'public_controller/contact_method';
$route['aboout-us'] = 'public_controller/aboutus_method';
/*
 * other routes
 * here
 */
$route['(:any)'] = 'search/name/$1';
```

[Docs](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html?highlight=route#examples).

Also, don't forget to change links anchor in view files if needed (for static pages/variables).

Comment: Good. Consider of accepting answer as correct if so, to allow other with same/similar issue find solution easier. @willy-adams

Comment: if the URL is search/name/northern_ireland  then what i do.please share what i do for underscore.

Comment: As you could read in docs, placeholder `(:any)` accepts any string consisting allowed characters defined in `APPPATH . 'config.php'`. So `example.com/northern_ireland` will looks for logic in `example.com/search/name/northern_ireland`.

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
$route['france'] = 'search/name/france';
```

then in `<a>` should bee

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url()?>france
```