# How to change URL of some pages but not all pages in codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I have a problem related to codeigniter url structure currently my URL look like *www.abc.com/search/name/page_name*
but I want *www.abc.com/page_name* like structure for that I add some code in routes.php

```
$route['(:and)'] = 'search/name/$1';
$route['(:any)'] = 'search/name/$1';
```

After adding that code my all pages get redirected to search page and search page open rightly with page name, my ajax login not worked and detailed page not open what I do.please kindly reply i am very tenseI

Comment: Check again [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31862195/how-to-rewrite-url-in-codelgniter/31865115#answer-31865115) answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Hi adams, For url rewriting just use following :
>
> **Lets take a simple example:**
>
> Yourcontroller.php

```
class Yourcontroller extends CI_Controller { 
       function function_name(){
            echo "i am here";   
       }    
       function function_name1($id,$name){
        echo $id." - ".$name;   
       } 
 }
```

> Routes.php
>
> ```
> $route['function_name'] = 'yourcontroller/function_name';
> $route['function_name1/(:num)/(:any)'] = 'yourcontroller/function_name1/$1/$2';
> ```
>
> > u can access ur method by following url
> >
> > Ex: www.abc.com/yourcontroller/function_name OR  www.abc.com/function_name
> >
> > Example2:use any or num for second metod $route['function_name/(:num)/(:any)']
> >     ='yourcontroller/function_name/$1/$2'; Ex: www.abc.com/function_name/1/adams

Comment: sir if i want to open my url like abc.com/some name/some name/some name    then what route i set

Comment: just use $route['function_name1/(:any)/(:any)(:any)'] = 'yourcontroller/function_name1/$1/$2/$3';